# Cakephp is returning error 302

Tags: php, session, cakephp, session-cookies

I have a very weird behavior is happens in cake php.

Just in production, some action is returning error 302 when the user is logged.

I cannot reproduce this in development environment, but randomly, the session dies and the action return 302.

This week happens a problem in the server disk, this server is from a thirdy partner, and I don't know if there is a relationship between this. But I know that the server is unstable last days.

I tried to log some stack, but nothing is logged in the cakephp.

The session method is using cookies, but this problem happens without the cookies.

**My hypothesis are:**

1. the disk has some problem and lose the session files.
2. could exist a bug in cakephp 2.4.5and it is causing the session lost
3. there is goblin inside the server doing mess.

Could you help me? I had this problem for 3 weeks.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know if Authentication is ever successful on production? what does your login action look like in the controller?

Comment: The authentication is ever succesfull because I return the userId from the session and echo it on the view.

This is the login function:

'
//The loginUser is called after user and password are validated on the data base
private function loginUser( $user ) {
  if ( $user ) {
   $this->logout();
   if( $this->Auth->login( $user['User'] ) ) {
    $this->refreshSession( $user['User'] );
    return true;
   }
  } else
   $result = $this->User->validationErrors;
 }
'

Comment: protected function refreshSession( $user ){
  $this->Session->write( 'Auth.User', $user );

  //Carregando poster para a sessão
  $this->loadModel( 'Announce' );
  $poster = $this->Announce->find( 'first', array( 'conditions' => array( 'Announce.int_user_id' => $user[ 'int_user_id' ] ) ) );
  $this->Session->write( 'Auth.Poster', @$poster[ 'Announce'] );
        
        if( @$this->Cookie )
            $this->Cookie->write( 'rbUserSession', $user, true, 1200 );
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, maybe could be correlated with the way on which PHP works with sessions. PHP saves all sessions on a directory, that you can get with the php_session_path function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php. If this directory it's located on the disk that you said, or is related on another way, you will have problems.

Comment: there is no `PHP` function called `php_session_path()`. Did you mean `session_save_path()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the server disk. Our partners did the system migration to other machine and now everything is fine.

Thanks